# Timestamp issue in oracle schedule jobs

Tags: oracle, timestamp, jobs

I wrote a procedure to dump dba_audit_trail information to a flat file and once it done purge the sys.audit table. Execute the procedure manually it dump the data correctly to flat file. But it execute as a schedule job TIMESTAMP is not correct. TIMESTAMP is 6 hours less than TIMESTAMP in dba_audit_trail table.

---

```
Table content
------------------------
31-07-2014 07:26:08,EOMCBOFD,CFNET\CBOEDPS5,Administrator,CBOEDPS5,LOGON,,
31-07-2014 07:26:24,EOMCBOFD,CFNET\CBOEDPS5,Administrator,CBOEDPS5,LOGOFF BY CLEANUP,,
```

---

```
Flat file content
-------------------
31-07-2014 01:26:08,EOMCBOFD,CFNET\CBOEDPS5,Administrator,CBOEDPS5,LOGON,,
31-07-2014 01:26:24,EOMCBOFD,CFNET\CBOEDPS5,Administrator,CBOEDPS5,LOGOFF BY CLEANUP,,

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYS.ddl_audit_log_purge AS
 CURSOR cur_date IS`enter code here`
     SELECT sysdate FROM dual;

     rec1 cur_date%ROWTYPE;
     created_file_name VARCHAR2(100);
     file_name UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

     BEGIN
      OPEN cur_date;
  LOOP
  FETCH cur_date INTO rec1;
  EXIT WHEN cur_date%NOTFOUND;
  created_file_name:=rec1.sysdate;
  file_name:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('AUD_DIR','cfcbo_'||created_file_name||'.exp','W');

        FOR rec in(
           SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
           ||','||username
           ||','||userhost
           ||','||os_username
           ||','||terminal
           ||','||action_name
           ||','||owner                
           ||','||obj_name
           out_line
           FROM dba_audit_trail)
        LOOP
             UTL_FILE.PUTF(file_name,'%s\n',rec.out_line);
             UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file_name);
        END LOOP;
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file_name);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur_date;
  insert into aud_log_job (now,task) values(sysdate,'exported audit table');  
  execute immediate 'truncate table sys.aud$';  
  insert into aud_log_job(now,task) values(sysdate,'truncate audit table');  
  END;
  /
```

Comment: I suspect that has nothing to do with audit_trail, it is just a timezone issue, which is probably set up differently in your logon session and the scheduler setup?

Comment: Are `systimestamp` and `current_timestamp` six hours different? What time zone are the server and the client you ran this manually from in?

Comment: For Alex : Server timestamps are : SYSTIMESTAMP
----------------------------------------
31-JUL-14 03.32.28.975090 PM +06:00 and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
-----------------------------------------------
31-JUL-14 03.33.32.854273 PM +06:00  And Client time stamps are same as server

Comment: For ben and  wolφi : Yes i think so. I did the same in test ENV. same result. Ill attached the procedure herewith.

Comment: I wrote a server cronjob. It seems works fine that way.

Comment: I executed the procedure through cron job. Now its works fine. Still I haven't any idea abt Oracle job issue....

Comment: Add this line after the Bigin command. It Works.    execute immediate 'alter session set time_zone = ''+06:00''';

Comment: I suggest to use timezone names rather than fixed values. With names like "Europe/London" Oracle handles also daylight saving times.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite complicated issue. Check this Oracle support node: 
**DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB And DST / Timezones Explained (Doc ID 467722.1)**

"The sysdate and systimestamp "seen" by jobs may be different then the one when you connect, the used timezone is the one that was set when the database (!) was started."